# Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, joomla, cpanel

The website won't open and displays the "Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL." message.
i found the Config file in the cpanel for Joomla, but i do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Could you provide some additional information? Did you check the log files?

Comment: Could you tell us if you have direct access to the server(s) hosting your website and your mysql db? They are on the same server on on different ones? The config file of joomla shows the correct configuration of your mysql database in term of IP Address and user login account (username/password).

Comment: this is the address, http://ethiopianrun.org

and yes i have access to the cpanel, but not the joomla